# How to mark `//` conditions uncoverable with Devel::Cover?

Tags: perl, devel-cover

I have the following logic:

```
sub test {
    my ($x, $y) = @_;
    die unless defined $x || defined $y;
    # uncoverable condition false
    return $x // $y;
}

test( 1,     2     );
test( 1,     undef );
test( undef, 2     );
test( undef, undef );
```

The `return` statement will never be covered for the condition where `$x` and `$y` are both undefined. So the coverage report points out that condition as uncovered:

```
  %  | coverage    | condition
 ------------------------------
  67 | A | B | dec | $x // $y
     |-------------|
===> | 0 | 0 |  0  | 
     | 0 | 1 |  1  |
     | 1 | X |  1  |
```

Is there a way for me to mark that condition as `uncoverable`? Adding `uncoverable condition false` above the line fixes the coverage summary, but when I look at the details the condition coverage is still at 67%.

Does Devel::Cover handle the `//` operator?

---

On another note, if I change the `die` line to the equivalent:

```
die "died" if !defined $x && !defined $y;
```

that line also becomes 67% covered.

```
  %  | coverage    | condition
 ------------------------------
  67 | A | B | dec | defined $x or defined $y
     |-------------|
     | 0 | 0 |  0  | 
===> | 0 | 1 |  1  |
     | 1 | X |  1  |
```

Could that be a bug?

Comment: What version of Devel::Cover are you running?

Comment: The version I'm using is 1.08 (Strawberry Perl 5.18, if that makes any difference)

Answer (score 1):

That makes no sense. `//` only has two paths (`$x` is defined, `$x` is not defined). `$y` is not relevant for the `//`. So I ran a test

```
test( 1,     2     );
#test( 1,     undef );   # Don't even need this one.
test( undef, 2     );
test( undef, undef );
```

Got:

```
----------------------------------- ------ ------ ------ ------ ------ ------
File                                  stmt   bran   cond    sub   time  total
----------------------------------- ------ ------ ------ ------ ------ ------
x.pl                                 100.0  100.0  100.0  100.0  100.0  100.0
Total                                100.0  100.0  100.0  100.0  100.0  100.0
----------------------------------- ------ ------ ------ ------ ------ ------
```

Comment: Your answer makes sense to me, and that's what I originally thought. But that's not what my report said. Did you run that with the `uncoverable` spec removed?

Comment: @stevenl, ah, no. ...except I get the same result after removing it. Devel::Cover 1.08, Perl 5.16.3